# Prove there are no sets $x,y$ such that $x\in y$ and $y\in x$

Tags: set-theory

How to prove there are no sets $x,y$ such that $x\in y$ and $y\in x$ according to axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I should remark that there's a decent change that the duplicate is itself a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $z:=\{x,\,y\}$ so $x\cap z=\{y\},\,y\cap z=\{x\}$, contradicting regularity.